# Python Conditional Enumeration with Replacement

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, enumeration

I have a dataframe called **fleet_df** that looks like this:

```
Vehicle_ID     Capacity
001            5
002            6
003            10
```

I also have the a variable **total_demand**:

```
total_demand = 55
```

What I want is to **enumerate all combinations with replacement** of vehicles so long as the sum of Total_Capacity is greater than or equal to total_volume and less than or equal to double the total_volume.

Example output:

```
Scenario     Vehicle_IDs                           Total_Capacity
1            001, 001, 001, 003, 003, 003, 003     55
2            003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003     70
...
```

I thought something like this would work, but no luck so far:

```
enumerate(i for i in fleet_df['Capacity'].values.tolist() if (total_demand <= i) and (i <= total_demand * 2))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a total capacity (55) and some items with a weight (5, 6, 10) you can use each item as many time as needed and you want all combinations of these items such that the sum of their weights is less or equal to 55?

Comment: @cglacet You are mostly correct, except I'm looking for all combinations of the items such that the sum of their weights is greater than or equal to 55 and less than or equal to 110.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to do something like this - get the combinations of the row indices, for each combination of rows find the sum of capacity and filter them based on the condition

```
fleet_df = pd.DataFrame({'Vehicle_ID': ['001', '002', '003'],
                         'Capacity': [5, 6, 10]})
# Set the index as 'Vehicle_ID'
fleet_df.set_index(['Vehicle_ID'], inplace=True)
total_demand = 55
n = 10
final_df = pd.DataFrame([])

for i in range(1, n):
    comb_indices = list(comb for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(fleet_df.index, r=i))
    comb_rows = pd.DataFrame([fleet_df.loc[comb, 'Capacity'].sum() for comb in comb_indices],
                             index=comb_indices, columns=['Total Capacity'])
    final_df = final_df.append(comb_rows[(comb_rows['Total Capacity'] >= total_demand) & (comb_rows['Total Capacity'] <= 2*total_demand)])


final_df = final_df.rename_axis('Vehicle_IDs').reset_index().rename_axis('Scenarios')
print(final_df)
```

Explanation:

The line

```
list(comb for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(fleet_df.index, r=i))
```

will get you the combinations of all indices from `fleet_df` with `i` elements from `0 to n`. So, with `i=2` you will have `comb_indices` as

```
[('001', '001'), ('001', '002'), ('001', '003'), ('002', '002'), ('002', '003'), ('003', '003')]
```

Next, create a temporary dataframe `comb_rows` with the row matching the indices in the combination `comb_indices`

```
comb_rows = pd.DataFrame([fleet_df.loc[comb, 'Capacity'].sum() for comb in comb_indices], index=comb_indices, columns=['Total Capacity'])
```

Finally, append the matching rows with total capacity meeting the required total demand to the `final_df`

```
comb_rows[(comb_rows['Total Capacity'] >= total_demand) & (comb_rows['Total Capacity'] <= 2*total_demand)]
```

Once you have the `final_df` rename the indices as you want.

Here the value of `n` is the number of elements in each combination. When `n` increases I don't know this will be an efficient solution. And `n` depends on the `total_demand` as there can be infinite possibilities with repetition controlled by the `total_demand` value. As the `total_demand` value increases way more than the individual capacity of vehicles, the value of `n` should also go higher to meet all combinations.
The range of `n` can be bounded as `total_demand/max(capacity)` to `(2*total demand)/min(capacity)`. I think you should get all the matching combinations within this. So, in this case, your range of `n` will be

```
min_comb = int(total_demand/max(fleet_df['Capacity'].to_list()))
max_comb = int((2*total_demand)/min(fleet_df['Capacity'].to_list()))
for i in range(min_comb, max_comb+1):
    ...
    ...
```

Final result:

```
                                             Vehicle_IDs  Total Capacity
Scenarios                                                               
0                         (001, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              55
1                         (002, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              56
2                         (003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              60
3                    (001, 001, 001, 003, 003, 003, 003)              55
4                    (001, 001, 002, 003, 003, 003, 003)              56
...                                                  ...             ...
71         (002, 002, 002, 002, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              74
72         (002, 002, 002, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              78
73         (002, 002, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              82
74         (002, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              86
75         (003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003, 003)              90
...                                                      ...         ...
828        (001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, ...         107
829        (001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, ...         108
830        (001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, ...         109
831        (001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, ...         110
832        (001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, ...         110

[833 rows x 2 columns]
```

May be there is a better solution for higher values, but this should work with the sample data set.